# How can I export env variables to a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

#### Objective

I have an env variable script file that looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export FOO="public"
export BAR="private"
```

I would like to source the env variables to be available when a docker image is being built. I am aware that I can use `ARG` and `ENV` with build args, but I have too many Env Variables, and I am afraid that will be a lengthy list.

It's worth mentioning that I only need the env variables to install a specific step in my docker file (will highlight in the Dockerfile below), and do not necessarily want them to be available in the built image after that.

#### What I have tried so far

I have tried having a script (`envs.sh`) that export env vars like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export DOG="woof"
export CAT="meow"
```

My Docker file looks like:

```
FROM fishtownanalytics/dbt:0.18.1
# Define working directory
# Load ENV Vars
COPY envs.sh envs.sh
CMD ["sh", "envs.sh"]
# Install packages required
CMD ["sh", "-c", "envs.sh"]
RUN dbt deps # I need to env variables to be available for this step

# Exposing DBT Port
EXPOSE 8081
```

But that did not seem to work. How can I export env variables as a script to the docker file?

Comment: Can I at least get an explanation on how to make my question more clear, useful or show research effort before after getting a dowvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, you can't set environment variables in a `RUN` command: each `RUN` command runs a new shell in a new container, and any environment variables you set there will get lost at the end of that `RUN` step.

However, you say you only need the variables at one specific step in your Dockerfile.  In that special case, you can run the setup script and the actual command in the same `RUN` step:

```sh
FROM fishtownanalytics/dbt:0.18.1
COPY envs.sh envs.sh
RUN . ./envs.sh \
 && dbt deps
# Anything that envs.sh `export`ed is lost _after_ the RUN step
```

(`CMD` is irrelevant here: it only provides the default command that gets run when you launch a container from the built image, and doesn't have any effect on `RUN` steps.  It also looks like the [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/fishtownanalytics/dbt/0.18.1/images/sha256-be84f7e226039650c5e3bd437984be340b6ac7eaf095e9c5a788363d5295deb7?context=explore) declares an `ENTRYPOINT` so that you can only run `dbt` subcommands as `CMD`, not normal shell commands.  I also use the standard `.` to read in a script file instead of `source`, since not every container has a shell that provides that non-standard extension.)

Answer (score 0):

Your `CMD` call runs a new shell (sh) that defines those variables and then dies, leaving the current process unchanged. If you want those environment variables to apply to the current process, you could `source` it:

```
CMD ["source", "envs.sh"]
```

Comment: Hi @Mureinik. That makes total sense to me. However I still see that my `RUN dbt deps` step does not pick up the env variables. Am I doing one of the steps incorrectly?